# Cannot read .blk file C++ (Visual Studios)?

Tags: c++, file, hex

for my project I have a .blk file containing strings of binary data. And I would like to read that file, but I get a blank line when I cout the file. **When I import the .blk file, Visual Studios already has the file in hex display: 00 00 FF 91 FD 00. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I have tried looking around Google and StackOverflow but nothing quite what I'm looking for. I tried "cout << hex" to see what I get, but as mentioned before I'm not getting something like: 00 00 FF 81 FD 00. **Not sure if it would make a difference, but I imported the .blk file into my source files onto Visual Studios.

```
    char data;//changed the datatype to different ones [string, int, char, float]

    fin.open("data.blk");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
    cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
    }
else{
    fin >> data;}

    while (fin)
    {
        cout << hex << data << endl;
        fin >> data;
    }
}
```

I expect the out to be in hex display from the file: B7 E0 00 00 FF 81 80 05 FD ED...

Comment: What output *do* you see?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I do not get an output, just a blank line.

Comment: Try `cout << hex << unsigned(data)`

Comment: Tried it..didn't work. Since Visual Studios displays the .blk file into hex display, does it affect how we read it (treat it as hex or binary?)

Comment: You are in learning mode. Separate the tasks. Use a debugger. First try reading the blk into a `std::string` Then decide what you want to do with it like output it to `cout` look up the function `std::getline`  `cin` will break up the input at white spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after numerous tweaking the day after, just wanted to keep you guys updated that I was able to figure it out.

A few of my mistakes was:

-the way the file was read (VS has a specific standard in adding a file into the directory)

-since the file is in binary, the file read syntax is ->`fin.open("data.blk", ios::binary);`

-when you want binary in hex, the syntax is -> `cout << hex << (binary integer)`

Below is my finished product with all the fixed mistakes:

```
    //READ FILE
fin.open("data.blk", ios::binary);

//CHECK IF THE FILE IS READ
if (!fin)
{
    cout << "Cannot open file" << endl;
}
else
{
    //OBTAIN FILE SIZE
    fin.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int file_size = (fin.tellg());

    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    uint16_t* data = new uint16_t[file_size];//ALLOCATE MEMORY TO STORE UNSIGNED 16 BIT INTEGERS <- groups the binary in groups of 4

    fin.read((char*)data, file_size);//stores file data into data

    for (int i = 0; i < file_size / 2; i++)
    {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(4) << hex << data[i] << " " << endl;//setfill('0') and setw(4) fills the hex values to have 4 characters or 8 bits in display
    }
}
```